# R functions that print plots won't resolve

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I've seen other questions here about RStudio not displaying plots, but in my case, R won't even finish the computation. At first I thought it had to do with the size of the datasets, but commands like `plot(rnorm(50), rnorm(50))` yield the same result. I can create `ggplot` objects but cannot print them. The memory usage slowly trickles down to <10MiB, and only by terminating the R session can I exit. The problem randomly started on the ~400th iteration of a for loop that was calling `car::confidenceEllipse`. Can anyone explain to me why I might be experiencing this bug?

I tried updating both R and RStudio. I tried `dev.off` down to the null device. The same behavior persisted.

I am running the latest versions of R and RStudio on MacOS 12.1

Comment: There isn't a lot of detail here about what code you're running 400 times and how you're saving the output along the way. It sounds like some sort of memory issue but it will be hard for people to give specific suggestions without more detail.

Comment: Does this behave differently when run from R outside of the RStudio IDE? If it works, then this should be a bug report to them; if not, then we need to remove the [tag:rstudio] tag.

Comment: @r2evans Doesn't work in the default R interface either. removed

Comment: @JonSpring the dataset was ~670000 observations of 7 variables. I didn't write the function but basically it takes and modifies a subset, runs a `nls` model on it, then calls `confidenceEllipse` with the model to produce output which gets `rbind`ed to the data frame to be returned

Comment: I agree with @JonSpring, this is too vague to give a concrete diagnosis or offer recommendations. Error codes or the code itself are needed. Generally, memory usage is a common problem in R and for-loops are a quick way to have them. See the second circle (Growing Objects) in this classic: https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf

Comment: ++++1 check out the Growing Objects chapter of R Inferno. It sounds like putting the output into a list and using `rbind` on that at the end might fix your problem.